# Create Docusign documents and send emails from another system

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi, apex

I am trying to integrate Salesforce and Docusign. I'd like to send Create documents through a soap / rest call, and surpress the notification to the recipient. From Salesforce I'd like to send out the link to the envelope / documents through a branded email.

Is that possible? It seems like DS only supports a createAndSend call.

This documentation says I can create an envelope in draft form - https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/ . It also says I get an envelope summary as a response.

https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/#/definitions/envelopeSummary

Comment: You can have branded email from DocuSign itself. On another note, DocuSign supports two type of Signing, first is called Remote SIgning where a notification will go from DocuSign to the signer and DocuSign will host the signing ceremony and you cannot stop this notification to go to the signer. Other one is Embedded Signing, where Customer's Application will host the Signing ceremony and it is possible to not send email notification to the customer, in this scenario you will invite your customer to come to your app and you will host the signing ceremony from your app.

Comment: https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/usage/embedded_signing.html has details of embedded signing, and yes you can create a draft envelope both by SOAP and REST.

Comment: @AmitKBist thank you so much. we want to direct the user to the docusign website, but want the url to be in an email. Is that possible? with embedded signing, I'd have to build out a webpage, no?

Comment: With embedded Signing you cannot send DocuSign signing URL in an email. Instead you can send url of your portal in an email (either from your SF or using DocuSign) where you want the user to be visiting to complete the signing ceremony. Once user visits your portal and ready to sign the document then you need to generate signing url as describer in - https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createRecipient/

Comment: Got it. Thanks @am

Comment: I would suggest to first decide between remote signing or embedded signing, as email notification can be branded in DocuSign for remote signing.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, Embedded Signing is the answer here. I've just done this with a client.

You would build the envelope with the SOAP API (good receipies from DocuSign on how to do this with APEX here: https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/docusign-for-salesforce).
When you define the Recipient, you would provide the ClientUserId in a CaptiveInfo object (use the ContactId for this). This tells DocuSign to skip sending the recipient an email, and you will handle this yourself.
Create and send the envelope (you can use templates as well).

You will need a portal or public Force.com site to move forward. The reason being that the URL for signing is a one-time-use link, and it expires 5 mins after it's generated. So you can't store it or send it in an email. By the time they click the link it will be dead.

So instead, you link to a Visualforce page you control. Add the ContactId to the URL as a parameter, so you know who is looking at the page.
When they load the page, you should have the Visualforce controller lookup the EnvelopeId (so if the page is about an Opportunity, you should store the EnvelopeId on the Opp or somewhere handy) and the recipient (use the ContactId to get the info about the recipient).
You then send this to DocuSign with the RequestRecipientToken method. It will return the token URL, and you can present it to the user.

Comment: THIS IS AWESOME!!!! A couple of questions. in the vf controller, am i re-directing the user to the DS url for the envelope or one of the documents? Also, is it a re-direct, or is there  an embedded iframe? Finally, any compliance issues? thanks @Michael Mock

Comment: In the VF controller, you will ultimately redirect the user to the URL you get back from the RequestRecipientToken method. You could also iframe it into an existing page, but that usually doesn't work out great with cross-site security. With the redirect, you can provide return URLs for all the possible scenarios (with specific URL parameters, so you can build out a whole process of handling their signing actions.

Comment: The only compliance issue you will have is that with public Force.com sites, you can't use Per User Named Credentials, you will have to specify a Named Principal (basically, a system user) for the guests to use to get the recipient token. It's not great, but not the end of the world.